# C#, DataTables, Primary Keys, and Select performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I have a C# application that has a large `DataTable` in memory. I need to do a `DataTable.Select` with a search filter to subset the data. Would adding a primary key to the table help with data retrieval performance? Are there other tricks that can be played to get fastest performance in sub-setting a `DataTable`?

This is what I am doing currently;

```
using (DataTable datThisProduction = datProduction.Select("IDColumn = '" + strThisID + "'", "DateColumn ASC").CopyToDataTable())
```

I need to search on the `IDColumn` and then sort by `DataColumn`. Should the primary key include both columns?

I looked for other postings about `DataTable` primay keys and there seemed to be uncertainties if primary keys helped.

Comment: Worse case scenario is you do add the PK to the DataTable, and compare execution time ?

Comment: Please give some more details: How many total rows? Only 1 single row with "ThisID"? Where does your data come from (RDBMS or any other source/process)? What does "DataTable in memory" mean exactly? Where do you want to add a PK? If there is an RDBMS (which?): Why don't you read this row directly (via index)?

Comment: Lots of data.  1,000 items (identified by the ID) with 200+ rows per item.  I read this from SQL Server into a DataTable object in C#.  I then need to extract the rows for each item item.  I could read the data from the database for each item, one item at a time.  But I am trying to reduce the amount of trips to the database.  I am hoping that processing the data in memory will be faster than multiple trips to the database.  I found code about adding a Primary Key to a DataTable object, one the DataTable is filled.  I am wondering if this would speed extracting the rows for each item.

Comment: I will do more performance testing, just wanted to see if anyone else had approaches to also try.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple with Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication57
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable ThisProduction = new DataTable();
            datThisProduction.Columns.Add("IDColumn", typeof(int));
            datThisProduction.Columns.Add("DataColumn", typeof(int));
            init strThisID = 123;

            DataTable datThisProduction = ThisProduction.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<int>("IDColumn") == strThisID)
                .OrderBy(y => y.Field<int>("DataColumn"))
                .CopyToDataTable();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this and measure performance vs. what I first tried.

Comment: Fastest approach is for the database to perform the filtering.  Not sure if you method does that.  Mine does the filtering in C# code.  I believe the best approach would be to write a stored procedure in the SQL Server database.

Comment: You are surely right with your opinion to let the database do the job. But you should prefer an "inline UDF" if you just read data. Stored Procedures **can** be used for this, but are meant for something else...

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you deal with "lots of data". Believe me, "1000 items" with about 200 sub-items each is not "lots of data" :-)

If performance is an issue with so little data your problems are somewhere else...

**You are mixing two concepts**

Speaking about DataTable and Primary Key is a database topic. This is best to be done within your RDBMS (SQL Server as you write). Create a nice structure there, implement the right indices and you won't have any performance problems...

One should not try to do the database's job within application's code...

**Multi-Layer**

It is something else if you transfer your datarows into business objects. There are very specialised collections (e.g. `KeyedCollection`) which are created to implement exactly this need. But you should - for cleanness! - have a clean cut between your data layer and your business objects. Normally we do not speak about objects from `System.Data-namespace` there...

**Scalability and multi-user-behaviour**

In this point of view your approach (load everything into the application's memory and deal with the data there) is far the worst...

**Conclusio**

It depends on your needs if "reading data on demand" or if a business object layer with permanent objects is better.

You can solve your problem easily with Linq (but Linq is not fast, it's using Reflection), with a specialised collection and even with a primary key within your application - but this is not the best approach.

There is good support in `typed datasets`, EF and all ORM-tools with relations. In this case your items and your sub-data would be in 1:n-related tables. The generated objects will have methods like "MyParentItem" or "MyChildrenList".